# Minimizing a monomial function subject to inequality constraints

Tags: linear-programming, nonlinear-programming

Assuming an objective function is a multivariable polynomial with real coefficients, in variables {x1, x2, ..., xn} with all exponents no larger than 1, and with linear inequalities on the variables, what are some good sources and/or approaches?

For instance:

Minimize .3 x1 - .5 x2 + .4 x3 + .9 x1 x2 - x1 x2 x3

subject to

0 <= x1

0 <= x2

0 <= x3

x1+x2 <= .9

x2+x3 >=.3

to find the solution (x1,x2,x3)=(0,.9,0).

Comment: Yes, (x1,x2,x3)=(0,.9,0). achieving the  objective value -0.45, is the global minimum solution, to your example problem; and is easily obtained using any of the techniques mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 6):

The objective function you described is called multilinear.

Although not necessarily the best way of solving this problem, it can be "lifted" into a higher dimensional space, thereby becoming a non-convex quadratic objective subject to non-convex quadratic constraints; specifically becoming a bilinear optimization problem. That is accomplished by introducing  new variables for various products of variables in such a manner that there are no products involving more than 2 variables. Such a formulation can then be solved with a bilinear solver, such as Gurobi, which can solve it to global optimality if it doesn't run out of time or memory. (Note that CPLEX's QCQP solver could not be used because it does not allow non-convex quadratic constraints).

In you example, introduce variables `x1_2` and `x1_2_3`, along with constraints

```
x1_2 = x1*x2
x1_2_3 = x1_2*x3
```

The objective can then be written as `.3 x1 - .5 x2 + .4 x3 + .9 x1_2 - x1_2_3`.

This formulation can be provided to any solver which can handle any combination of non-convex quadratic objective and quadratic equality constraints (in addition to the linear constraints your problem has).

If you use a more general purpose non-convex global solver, you can provide it either the "lifted" formulation as shown above, or enter your original formulation as is.  In such case, it might be better to use the original formulation, and let the solver handle any reformulations.

Another approach is to directly provide one of the above formulations to a local non-convex optimizer, in which case I suspect the original formulation might be best.

Answer (score 3):

To some extent, the answer depends on whether the objective function is convex (assuming minimization) or not. One general approach would be to approximate the objective with a piecewise linear function. With a convex objective, this would be an LP. Otherwise, it would be a MIP. There may also be a version/generalization of [McCormick envelopes](https://optimization.mccormick.northwestern.edu/index.php/McCormick_envelopes) that would be useful.

Comment: Thank you! I have not studied McCormick envelopes, will do so.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use a Global solver such as LINGO, thus:

Min= .3*x1 - .5*x2 + .4*x3 + .9*x1* x2 - x1*x2* x3;

!subject to;

! Variables are >= 0 by default;

x1+x2 <= .9;

x2+x3 >=.3;

Global optimal solution found.

Objective value:    -0.4500000

Objective bound:    -0.4500000

```
 Variable           Value     
       X1        0.000000    
       X2        0.900000        
       X3        0.000000          

      Row    Slack or Surplus     
        1       -0.450000         
        2        0.000000         
        3        0.600000
```